# Views filter (contextual?) by Taxonomy id

Tags: views

Have a question.

I have a D8 website for our company. This website contains service pages and now I would like to add a block with reviews on every service page. But the reviews should match the service.
The website has taxonomy vocabulary with all the services. So when I create a service page I have to choose a service from taxonomy (basically, one service page represents one term id from taxonomy vocabulary). And when I create a new review I also have to choose a service from the same taxonomy vocabulary.

So now I would like to add a block with the reviews on the service page. But I have no idea how to make the reviews match with the service page where they are embedded.

Is there some kind of filter what match term IDs from different fields?
Regular filter, contextual filter? Tokens? Unfortunately, nothing worked for me :(

I could create different blocks for every single service ... but there would be a more universal solution.

Would be happy to get any help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Term ID as contextual filter.

When filter value is not available, select Provide Default value

For Type, select Term ID from URL

This is automatically pickup the term from your node, your view preview will go blank, because the actual view edit page does not have a term. It will show up when you look at the node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :)

Unfortunately, I do not have "Term ID from route context" for some reasons.

Comment: @user126902 turns out they recently renamed it to from URL.